# How to list down the mongodb collection's attribute?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

Hi in mysql we can retrieve columns of a table by following query

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE'
```

is there equivalent to this in mongodb ?

Comment: You cannot since there is no pre-defined schema for MongoDB collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an equivalent.  Something like this:

```
db.userTableColumns.find(
    { tableName: "MYTABLE" },
    { tableName: 1, columnName: 1, dataType: 1, dataLength: 1, _id: 0 }
)
```

Here's a handy comparison between SQL and MongoDb concepts:  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

Comment: Have you tested this?